# Unable to authenticate Google API with Oauth2

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-python-client

I had a Python script that I had authorized to access a Google Spreadsheet. But when now when I run it, it throws the exception:

```
oauth2client.client.AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_client: The OAuth client was not found.
```

My auth code looks like:

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('myapp-credentials.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    json_key['client_email'],
    json_key['private_key'], scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

I've not changed anything in the account, so I don't know why it would suddenly stop working. If I login to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials, I see the app is still registered. How do I diagnose this and re-enable its access? Googling this error unfortunately finds dozens of potential causes.

Answer (score 0):

The class `SignedJwtAssertionCredentials` has been [removed from the source code](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/dcd20c9375308979e45ae280ec102a28d2ca60d1#diff-d8b1525b7f161cbce2f6438636be9c38) as of February 5, 2016, and its functionality replaced with that of [`ServiceAccountCredentials`](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.service_account.html).  This may be causing your error.

It appears that you'll want to use something like the following to generate your `credentials`:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('myapp-credentials.json', scope)
```

This [Github issue thread](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/issues/401) might be helpful, as well.